# What is "clause 10" in the C++03 standard?

Tags: c++, standards

I was reading through the C++03 standard and noticed the usage of "Clause 10". Example:

> 8.5.1 Aggregates [dcl.init.aggr]
>
> 1. An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static
>      data members (clause 11), no base classes ***(clause 10)***, and no
>      virtual functions (10.3).

There is also Clause 9 and Clause 11. What does this mean, is it referring to some other section in the standard?

Comment: In the pdf, you can click on the 10 and it takes you to section `10 Derived classes [class.derived]`

Comment: @Joshua: or passed introductory contract law. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clause

Comment: There is a standard for standards! It says that you should use Clause, and not section or chapter.

Comment: That just means contract lawyers as a group have failed grammar. No wonder legalese is so hard to read.

Comment: @Joshua: you may have difficulty with the concept of a word with two distinct meanings, but in English you have no choice but to roll with it. Nobody failed any grammar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The clause is the topmost hierarchical thingy, i.e., clause 10 is §10. Informally people refer to those as "sections", but the standard calls them "clauses".

Comment: Specifically, clause 10 is the section that begins on page 167 and is titled "`10 Derived classes [class.derived]`".

Answer (score 1):

> What does this mean, is it referring to some other section in the standard?

Yes, it refers to the "chapters". Eg. Clause 9 Classes.